# Chain rule question

Tags: calculus

> Use chain rule to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ when:
>
> $f(x,y) = e^{xy}, x(u,v) = u^2 + v^2, y(u,v) = u^2 - v^2$

So I said:

> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial  x} \cdot \frac{\partial  x}{\partial  u} + \frac{\partial  f}{\partial  y} \cdot \frac{\partial  y}{\partial  u} =  e^{xy} \cdot ( 2uy + 2ux)$.

But the answer sheet does not agree with me.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: because $2vy$ should have been $2uy$.

Comment: yes yes I just mistyped the letters.
Still, it says its wrong (and edited my typo)

Comment: What does it say the correct solution should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are computing 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,v),$$

(this notation is a bit sloppy; I should introduce the function $g$, s.t. $g(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v))$ and compute the partial derivatives of the composition $f\circ g$)
so your expression must be a function of $u$ and $v$ (and not a mix of $u$, $v$, $x$ and $y$). Moreover

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(u,v)=2u.$$

In summary

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,v)=ye^{xy}2u+xe^{xy}2u=2ue^{xy}(x+y)=
2ue^{(u^2+v^2)(u^2-v^2)}(2u^2)=4u^3e^{u^4-v^4}.$$

I hope it helps!

Comment: Oh! I see that you did what I did after "In summary"... it is the same thing I did.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) The notation before "in summary" is the tricky part, I think.

Comment: I guess I only did not put  $x=u^2 + v^2 $ and $ y = u^2 - v^2$

Comment: I agree (after the edit). Now you are done!

Answer (score 1):

When $z=f(x,y)$ is a function which has continuous first derivatives,and moreover if $x$ and $y$ are differentiable functions respect to $u$ and $v$ then  $$f_u=f_xx_u+f_yy_u,~~~f_v=f_xx_v+f_yy_v$$ Or
 $$\begin{pmatrix}
  z_u & z_v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  z_x & z_y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  x_u & x_v \\
  y_v & y_v\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: this needs a long overdue +1!